# How can I go back to Mountain Lion from Mavericks

Tags: macos, imac

My question it simple: *How can I go back to Mountain Lion from Mavericks?*

My iMac (late 2010, Processor 3.4 GHz Core i7, Memory 8GB 1333 MHz DDR3) became EXTREMELY slow with Mavericks - It was great with Mountain Lion.

In the beginning I thought I had to do with Google Chrome, but now it get slow with pretty much every program.

Help!

Comment: Please don't be hasty! I am not saying that Mavericks is the best OS ever. But if you think your whole system is slower and your computer is that juiced up with RAM and CPU then I would lean towards an actual hardware issue. If you have a current backup of your files  than reboot into Recovery HD and verify your hard drive is good via Disk Utility

Answer (score 2):

[Looking on google](https://www.google.com/search?q=downgrade%20from%20mavericks%20to%20mountain%20lion&oq=downgrade%20from%20mavericks&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.5352j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8) would have avoid this question. As [Macworld UK](http://www.macworld.co.uk/news/mac/downgrade-mavericks-mountain-lion-how-roll-back-mac-os-x-109-108-earlier-3494785/) described it, here are the steps :

- Get a copy of Mountain Lion
- [Download](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433) the recovery Disk Assistant
- Create a recovery install Disk
- Restart in Recovery Mode
- Erase your Main HD.
- Install a fresh OS.

---

**BUT** :

IMHO, your computer should be fast enough to handle Mavericks. The problem isn't probably the system itself. You should look at the Activity Monitor to see if there are some anomalies (high memory pressure, high CPU% etc.)

Comment: I also agree with Matthieu, double check Activity Monitor to see if there are any rogue processes hogging CPU or RAM. How full is your HDD @Yiorgos?

Comment: Thanks for the good answer (and the comment). I'm going to close the question as a duplicate, feel free to add the answer to the linked question instead.